# Multiple polygons associated with one district in shapefile

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, geopandas, choropleth

I have shapefile district level of India and I wish to plot a choropleth map using Python and GeoPandas. In the shapefile, there are multiple polygons associated with some districts and also just 1 polygon for some. I am new to this and I think that for one region there should be just 1 polygon; hence I don't understand the multiple one. Can someone explain why is it so and what polygon I am supposed to use while plotting in case of multiple ones.

e.g.:

1. Multiple Values:

   ```
   South 24 Parganas   MULTIPOLYGON (((88.41639 21.89883, 88.41638 21...
   South 24 Parganas   MULTIPOLYGON (((88.56661 21.91009, 88.56715 21...
   South 24 Parganas   MULTIPOLYGON (((88.64000 21.92168, 88.64027 21...
   ```
2. Single Values:

   ```
   Nicobar Islands   MULTIPOLYGON (((92.78778 9.24417, 92.78889 9.2...
   North and Middle Andaman    MULTIPOLYGON (((93.64841 14.93487, 93.64917 14...
   South Andaman     MULTIPOLYGON (((93.83970 12.32082, 93.85775 12...
   ```

Comment: Maybe there is some attribute that are different between two parts of one district(?)? If not, or if it isnt important you can [dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/dissolve.html) your single part polygons into multipart

Comment: Or some district are composed of several part (think of enclave, exclave or islands)

Comment: @J.R I checked the map, it's not made up of several parts. But it got me thinking that maybe they all represent the same district just with minor variations in the coordinates (as can be seen). Is that possible?

Comment: Try to select the polygon in the attributes table and look what got selected in the map